# When giving the cabal simple build system a custom build hook, why are there two PackageDescription structures?

Tags: haskell, cabal

One can override cabal's simple build system's default build hook in `Setup.hs` with something of the form:

```
main = defaultMainWithHooks simpleUserHooks { buildHook = myBuildHook }
```

Where

```
myBuildHook :: PackageDescription -> LocalBuildInfo -> UserHooks -> BuildFlags -> IO ()
```

So we are given both `PackageDescription` and `LocalBuildInfo`, but if we [look at the latter](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/Cabal/latest/doc/html/Distribution-Simple-LocalBuildInfo.html#t%3aLocalBuildInfo) we can see that it contains the former with the record name `localPkgDescr`.

In light of this I ask:

1. Is there are reason we have two `PackageDescription`s?
2. If we hadn't overridden `buildHook`, which `PackageDescription` would be used?

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the first `PackageDescription` basically represents the raw `<pkg>.cabal` file, while the wrapped `PackageDescription` contains the "resolved" package description, where flags have been removed, and all conditionals have been resolved.

I was unable to more closely inspect a piece of code where both of these structures are used simultaneously, so I'm not a 100% certain of this behavior.